# How to auto-run a script when a condition is true?

Tags: python, scripting, autorun

Let's say I have the following python program:

```
def Is_it_Midnight(args):
    print("It's midnight!")
```

and I want the .py script to execute itself when a certain condition is true, say "when the clock strikes midnight".

Is that possible?

Comment: It's not about script , it's about your OS, which OS you use?

Comment: I use OS X Sierra.
Is it possible to make it portable?

Comment: Time-based scripts are more a job for `cron`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the threading library to have the routine restart itself periodically. In this specific case, every 86400 seconds (1 day).

modify your code to:

```
import threading
import time

def Is_it_Midnight(args):
    threading.Timer(86400, Is_it_Midnight).start()
    print("It's midnight!")
```

Then you just have to get the code to run at midnight the first time. Something like:

```
seconds = time.time()
since_midnight = seconds % 86400
time.sleep(86400-since_midnight)
Is_it_Midnight()
```

I'm not sure how you'd handle passing args into the routine.

Comment: If you want to pass some arguments, just pass them when the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to run a script.

My favorite is to create `myscript.py` and within it define a function, let's say `def alarm()...` and then in your main script:

```
import myscript
```

And when the time comes, call:

```
myscript.alar()
```

There is another way, you can call `execfile("myscript.py")`